# Javascript stop interval and action after

Tags: javascript, setinterval

My proble is about setintervall function. I call a function named `thrice()` when `first()` and `second()` execution is finished. There is no proble with that. The code below :

```
var oneFinish = false;
var twoFinish = false;

function first() {
    console.log("FUNCTION first RUNNING");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("first " + i);
    }
    console.log("FUNCTION first FINISH");
    oneFinish = true;
}

function second() {
    console.log("FUNCTION second RUNNING");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log("second " + i);
    }
    console.log("FUNCTION second FINISH");
    twoFinish = true;
}

function thrice() {
    var intev = setInterval(function () {
        if (oneFinish && twoFinish) {
            console.log("FUNCTION thrice RUNNING");
            oneFinish = false;
            twoFinish = false;
            clearInterval(intev);
        }
    }, 3000);
    console.log("FUNCTION thrice FINISH");
}

first();
second();
thrice();
```

The output is like this :

```
FUNCTION first RUNNING
first 0
first 1
first 2
first 3
first 4
FUNCTION first FINISH
FUNCTION second RUNNING
second 0
second 1
second 2
second 3
second 4
second 5
second 6
second 7
second 8
second 9
FUNCTION second FINISH
FUNCTION thrice FINISH
FUNCTION thrice RUNNING
```

You see at the **end** of the output, it's the problem `FUNCTION thrice FINISH` is executed before `FUNCTION thrice RUNNING`

Comment: have you heard about async?

Comment: Yes, I heard about it. Why downvote? Want more explanation? Or just dislike the question or why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because, all the content of function in setInterval is called after 3000 milisec. Its the goal of setInterval : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
var intev = setInterval(function () {
    if (oneFinish && twoFinish) {
        console.log("FUNCTION thrice RUNNING");
        oneFinish = false;
        twoFinish = false;
        clearInterval(intev);
    }
}, 3000);
console.log("FUNCTION thrice FINISH");
```

If you want fix the order, you have to put `console.log("FUNCTION thrice FINISH");` inside the callback function :

```
var intev = setInterval(function () {
    if (oneFinish && twoFinish) {
        console.log("FUNCTION thrice RUNNING");
        oneFinish = false;
        twoFinish = false;
        clearInterval(intev);
        console.log("FUNCTION thrice FINISH");
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: You didn't fix the problem, only explained it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is not the solution which interrest me! but the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you log start after 3 seconds, but you log end immediately. Try this:

```
function thrice() {
    var intev = setInterval(function () {
        if (oneFinish && twoFinish) {
            console.log("FUNCTION thrice RUNNING");
            oneFinish = false;
            twoFinish = false;
            clearInterval(intev);
            console.log("FUNCTION thrice FINISH");
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that you give me the explanation but I cant accept 2 answer, for altruism i choose @ali_o_kan

Comment: That's fine, his is more complete than mine now.